# Blazor WASM how to get data from .Net 6 API

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I’m unable to get data from .Net 6 API into Blazor WASM app.

Firefox shows the on the bottom the very often mentioned error:

[image]

I worked on this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly

To fix the CORS Problem I read this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I have no idea what I doing wrong. Please can someone have I look in my demo app on GitHub? I created a simple demo app.

https://github.com/Christoph1972/BlazorTestGetAPIData

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools and look at the console tab. Exceptions that happen in WASM are logged there. If an exception happens in your Web API, there will also be exception details logged in the console window that opens when you start debugging your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `CORS` you can do this:

```
options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://<YOUR_URL>")//The client Url that wants to get data
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));
```

and

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy"); <-----
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works perfect! I had only this option:

options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7096;http://localhost:5096");
                      });